# "How many minutes are left to LA?" vs "How many minutes are left to get to LA?"

Tags: usage

Are these sentences correct and interchangeable?

- **"How many minutes are left to LA?"**
- **"How many minutes are left to get to LA?"**

*Context*: Let's say I am on a bus that goes to Los Angeles and I wonder how many minutes later we're going to get to LA.

Comment: The second one is grammatically correct but very non-idiomatic.  It sounds like the speaker is asking how many minutes we have before we can leave for LA, like we have to leave for LA in the next 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

In a situation where a vehicle is heading for LA and the passenger asks the driver how much longer it will take to arrive in the city, the passenger might ask:

> How long (still) to LA

(An idiomatic, informal phrase)

> How much longer/further to LA?

(Another idiomatic, informal phrase)

> How much longer till we get to/reach LA?

Once more, a typical question but not a complete sentence!

> How long will it be before we reach/get to LA?

This time the question is posed as a proper sentence although most people are likely to use one of the shortcuts outlined above.

Neither of your examples is idiomatic although both make it clear that the questioner wants to know how much longer it will take.

It's probable that the questioner would say either:

> How many minutes (still) to LA?

or

> How many more minutes to LA?

Neither of these is a complete sentence although this is typically how people speak in these circumstances.

Few would say **How many more minutes will it take us to reach LA?** when **How much longer to LA** will suffice?

Comment: How about "*how much time (still) to LA?*"

Comment: It’s a typical question in the form of a phrase